# what is the mining of block reward at Etherscan?

Tags: etherscan, block-reward

When I searched out some block on Etherscan, I found out some strange thing.

For example, here is one of example: https://etherscan.io/block/9168614

[image]

Reward of this block is 2.18430490432165812 Ether (2 + 0.12180490432165812 + 0.0625)

2 ETH is mining reward and 0.12180490432165812 ETH is sum of tx fee.

## Then what is 0.0625 ETH?

It seem that the value is not reward for uncles

Comment: Oh, thank you for your confirmation. Finally I found that it is uncle reward. Thank you so much~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the comment from @Ismael, I finally clearly learned that the value is `uncle inclusion rewards`.

You can confirm when hovers your mouse point on the value ;)